# Outlook.com lost draft

Tags: outlook.com

Just now, I was working on a draft on outlook.com. I saved the draft and then started composing a new email. I finished sending the email and then went back into my Drafts to look at the draft I was previously working on. It has disappeared and is not to be found in any of the other folders either. How do I recover it?

FYI: I went back to Hotmail just to check and it is not there either.

Comment: If it's gone, it's gone. You don't get to sift through servers' temp files.

Comment: Thanks. I asked anyway because Outlook hasn't been around long and I was wondering if it was some kind of a bug or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, there is nothing to be done in such a situation.

This is the only time I've had an issue with a lost draft and this happened at a time when Outlook.com had just launched. All this to say that even the reason for why the draft suddenly disappeared will remain unknown.